# Comprehensive list of Android apps that detect and don't work with rooted phones

Tags: applications, rooting, root-access

I've been trying to determine if there is a comprehensive list of Android apps that have root detection built in and do not run if root is detected. Examples would be Good for Enterprise, Fox Digital Copy, Barclays Mobile Banking, and DIRECTV GenieGO.

Is there such a list?

Comment: How can it be comprehensive? There are new apps coming out all of the time.

Comment: Comprehensive as of today, or recently. Obviously there will be new apps, there isn't a list of any kind.

Comment: List questions like this aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange sites because they require a lot of continuing effort to keep up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

The most comprehensive list I've seen its available on the RootCloak website, towards the bottom...

http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Just for the record, I wrote that list after asking this question... :)